# How do I resolve the Error: GraphQL error: Unknown modifier: $pushAll in my react app?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, graphql

the compplete error message in my console is the ff:

bundle.js:6882 Uncaught (in promise) Error: GraphQL error: Unknown modifier: $pushAll
    at new ApolloError (bundle.js:6885)
    at bundle.js:15810

Anybody can show me how to resolve this problem?

I read in other threads or question that $pushAll is a mongoose version issue with nodejs.. is this the same $pushAll issue?

Thank you in advance!

Here is the graphql query:

```
mutation AddLyricToSong($content: String, $songId: ID) {
  addLyricToSong(content: $content, songId: $songId) {
    id
    title
    lyrics {
      content
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the query inside a js file..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

class LyricCreate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { content: '' };
  }

  onSubmithandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.mutate({
      variables: {
        content: this.state.content,
        songId: this.props.songId
      }
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (

        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmithandler.bind(this)}>
          <label>Add a Lyric</label>
          <input 
            value={this.state.content}
            onChange={(event) => this.setState({content: event.target.value})} 
           type="text"/>
        </form>

    )
  }
}

const mutation = gql`
mutation AddLyricToSong($content: String, $songId: ID) {
  addLyricToSong(content: $content, songId: $songId) {
    id
    title
    lyrics {
      content
    }
  }
}

`;

export default graphql(mutation)(LyricCreate);
```

Comment: as per answers and suggestions from similar question on mongoose and nodejs compatibility.. i downgraded the version of mongoose to ^3.4.11, and got a whole bunch of issues that my nodemon crashes.. so I revert back to my mongoose version 4.7.8 and back to my original question.. so, how do I resolve this error ? anyone?

Comment: can you post some of the code?

Comment: I added the codes and the graphql query.. thanks benjaminadk .. also, the query seems to pass through.. I checked the db and the new contents are there..

Comment: This is the response I got from my console..:

{"data":{"addLyricToSong":null},"errors":[{"message":"Unknown modifier: $pushAll","locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"path":["addLyricToSong"]}]}

the request headers are all fine and dandy, though. If this can help.

Comment: I have  been reading and researching this issue, it would seem to be a mongoose problem rather than graphQL or apollo.. my only doubt is that, why would my other query work while this particular query doesnt? I really hope someone can figure this out.. thanks guys..

Comment: wondering where `this.props.songId` comes from.  Would also be interested in the resolver code, assuming that is where the `$pushAll` takes place.  If code is on github just leave a link to it there.

Comment: I am equally excited to see what the resolution to this would be.. I am also researching and reading documentations.. and I think, I have a fairly good chance of resolving this too.. hope someone beat me to it to save me development time..

Comment: Whew!! finally got it resolved last night.. thanks guys.. am I allowed to place an answer to my own question? I think, no? anyway, the issue was more on mongoose rather than graphql and apollo.. after going back and forth here:  https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4455 ..